# Loaded data not showing | Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

MY error is that when you load the game the values go active (they work and increment) but the numbers doesn't load.

I have setup a codepen where you can see all my code and check out the error yourself

[CODEPEN LINK HERE](http://codepen.io/multiboy/pen/VYaERG)

1. Click a few times
2. Buy a mountain Dew
3. Press save
4. Refresh
5. Load

Now the mountain dew will autoclick every second but the mntDew value is not shown.

Please help, and thanks for checking this question out :)

```
var faze = 0;
function fazeClick(number){
    faze = faze + number;
    document.getElementById('faze').innerHTML = faze;
    var randomcolor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    scoep.style.color = randomcolor;
}
var mntDew = 0;
function buyDew(){
    var mntDewCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.2,mntDew));
        if(faze >= mntDewCost){
            mntDew = mntDew +1;
            faze = faze - mntDewCost;
            document.getElementById('mntDew').innerHTML = mntDew;
            document.getElementById('faze').innerHTML = faze;
        };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.2,mntDew));
    document.getElementById('mntDewCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem('faze', JSON.stringify(faze));
    localStorage.setItem('mntDew', JSON.stringify(mntDew));
    localStorage.setItem('mntDewCost', JSON.stringify(mntDewCost));
    //add more here
};
function load(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('mntDew')){
        mntDew = JSON.parse(localStorage['mntDew']);
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem('faze')){
        faze = JSON.parse(localStorage['faze']);
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem('mntDewCost')){
        mntDewCost = JSON.parse(localStorage['mntDewCost']);
    };


    //add more here
};
function deleteSave(){
    localStorage.removeItem("save");
};

window.setInterval(function(){
    fazeClick(mntDew);
}, 1000);


// <button type="button" onClick="buyDew()">Buy Mountain Dew</button> #buyCursor
//Mountain Dew: <span id="mntDew">0</span><br/> #cursors
//cost: <span id="mntDewCost">10</span> #cursorCost
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I didn't click the image at least 11 times, nothing happened when I would click mountain dew. I could save it and then click load and the numbers didn't change. The problem is not actually the JavaScript, but the design of the app.  The way it's set up, the user must click the image at least 11 times. After that when the user clicks mountain dew, you see the numbers change. As long as the user doesn't know to click the image, then variable faze has a value of 0 and that means this conditional will return false:

```
if(faze >= mntDewCost){
            mntDew = mntDew +1;
            faze = faze - mntDewCost;
            document.getElementById('mntDew').innerHTML = mntDew;
            document.getElementById('faze').innerHTML = faze;
        };
```

in byDew(). So faze gets saved with its value of zero and its zero value will load, too.